# ClassLoader: pretend that a class wasn't found so a child loader can handle it instead

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I want to make a subclass of [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) which, when [`loadClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-) is invoked, can examine the loaded class with reflection and conditionally decide to pretend it couldn't find that class, so as to allow for a child class loader to handle the loading instead.  Would something like the following work?

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> c = super.findClass(name);

    if (letChildHandleLoad(c))
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();

    return c;
}
```

Comment: What is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve. Because this is almost certainly not the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior for `loadClass` is to call `getParent().loadClass` and then `findClass`.  To get the behavior you're describing, typically you would not modify the parent class loader; instead, typically you would modify the child class loader by overriding the `loadClass` method to call `findClass` first.  That way, `loadClass` calls that originate with the child class loader will load the class from its local class path before the parent, but `loadClass` calls that originate with the parent class loader will work as expected.